# Why .Net 4.7 Web Application, packages target Dotnet 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

> Why does donet 4.7 project mentions targetFramework as Dotnet45 in
>   Package.Config

Assuming we're not interested in leveraging Dotnet Standard 2.0. Is it futile attempt to upgrade the project from .net 4.5 to 4.7?

```
<packages>
      <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="2.1.0" **targetFramework="net45"** />
</packages>
```

> It it even worth upgrading? Its MVC + Web API project?

Comment: Did you change the target framework for your project (from 4.5 to 4.7)? If yes : the package.config isn't updated. When updating the package or reinstalling the package, the "targetFramework" attribute will be updated to "net47". You do not need to worry about this; so far I didn't find any problems with a "wrong" targetFramework in the packages.config file.

Comment: @Styxxy Yes changed from .net 45 to .net 47. Other question - is it even worth upgrading? Its MVC Web API project

Comment: Did you use the latests VS 2017? If you select the target framework from the UI dropdown, it will attempt to reinstall all packages and change the packages.config (as long as your project builds)

Comment: @Abhijeet It all depends on you if it is worth it. Check the documentation what is changed : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/ .